# Erro deploy Heroku app Django

Tags: html, css, python, django, heroku

Após fazer o deploy no Heroku, fui abrir o link da minha aplicação (https://silima.herokuapp.com/), e a mesma apresentou o seguinte erro:

```
    ProgrammingError at /
relation "Produto" does not exist
LINE 1: ..., "Produto"."criado", "Produto"."modificado" FROM "Produto" ...
                                                             ^
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://silima.herokuapp.com/
Django Version: 2.0.3
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
relation "Produto" does not exist
LINE 1: ..., "Produto"."criado", "Produto"."modificado" FROM "Produto" ...
                                                             ^
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute, line 85
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.3
Python Path:    
['/app',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Qua, 23 Mai 2018 10:22:22 -0300
```

Comment: Após o deploy, você rodou as migrações de banco de dados do django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você não teve problemas no deploy, imagino que tenha adicionado o add-on do Postgres. Então o `heroku run python manage.py migrate` deve resolver o problema. Lembrando que antes você tem que estar logado (`heroku login`).

Comment: Show de bola, era isso mesmo, esqueci de dar o migrate, deu certo, agora estou com mais uma duvida, algumas imagens o Django não renderizou na minha pagina, não são todas, apenas algumas. Estou esquecendo de algo ?

Comment: Depende. Seriam imagens que você fez upload?

Comment: Então, essas imagens estão em uma pasta dentro da pasta static, estranho que outras imagens deram certo.

Comment: @GabrielGeorge acho que o melhor seria criar uma nova pergunta e jogar lá os detalhes, como a arvore de diretorio do seu projeto, seu `settings.py` e etc

Comment: Sim, verdade ! Vou fazer isso, mesmo assim, muito obrigado pela força!